# What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?

Tags: c, bit-shift

Consider the following code:

```
int i = 3 << 65;
```

I would expect that the result is `i==0`, however the actual result is `i==6`. With some testing I found that with the following code:

```
int i, s;
int a = i << s;
int b = i << (s & 31);
```

the values of `a` and `b` are always the same.

Does the C standard say anything about shifting more than 32 bits (the width of type `int`) or is this unspecified behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From my WG12/N1124 draft (*not* the standard, but Good Enough For Me), there's the following block in 6.5.7 *Bitwise shift operators*:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

So, *undefined*. Be careful.

Comment: "Good Enough For Me" -- good enough for everyone, since the standard contains exactly the same language. :-) Note that you can also obtain C99 + TC3 free at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf and it too has the same language, so even if you don't have the standard itself you can be pretty sure what it says!

Comment: You can also obtain a much more reader-friendly html version here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html

Comment: @R.., oh, thanks, that'll be way easier to read than the PDF. :)

Comment: @Jim: Thanks for the confirmation and link -- I can never find those links when I need them. :)