# bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results

Tags: c, bit-shift, unsigned

I'm a bit confused because I wanted to initialize a variable of type `unsigned long` whose size is 8 bytes on my system (on every modern system I suppose). When I want to assign `1 << 63` to the variable, I get a compiler warning however and the number is in fact 0. When I do `1 << 30` I get the expected result of `2 ^ 30 = 1073741824`. Yet when I do `1 << 31`, I get the result of `2 ^ 64` (I think; actually this shouldn't be possible) which prints `18446744071562067968`.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: did you try `1UL << 63`

Comment: No, never seen this notation (I'm pretty new to C), thanks :)

Comment: @OliverBorchert You can suffix a number with `U` for `unsigned` and `L` for `long` to change the type of that literal. There are some other suffixes, look in a C book for more details.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/25838378/995714

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the C standard say about bitshifting more bits than the width of type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`1 << 63` will be computed in `int` arithmetic, and your `int` is probably 32 bit.

Remedy this by promoting the left argument: `1ULL << 63` will do it.

`ULL` means the expression will be at least 64 bits.

Comment: Yeah ok, thank you, I'll accept the answer as soon as it is possible

Comment: actually `UL` is not 64 bits long on 32-bit architectures, `ULL` is.

Comment: Nitpicking, but unless it's been changed in a newer standard than the one I have, unsigned long isn't guaranteed to be more than 32 bits, since ULONG_MAX isn't guaranteed to be more than 4294967295.

Comment: wrong. `long` is just guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, and it's still 32 bits on 64-bit windows. Only `long long` are at least 64 bits, and you must use `ULL` for that

Comment: This answer is misleading. It says "by promoting one of the arguments", which seems to suggest that it is sufficient to promote any of the two arguments. In reality shift operators are *special* in the sense that changing the type of the right operand does not lead to promotion of the left operand. In this case it is important to change the type of the left operand specifically, not "one of the arguments" as this answer misleadingly suggests.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `1 << 63` has type `int`. The range of an `int` is -2<sup>31</sup> … 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 on most systems, 2<sup>63</sup> is too large for that. Try either `(unsigned long)1 << 63` or `1UL << 63` to shift a value of type `unsigned long` left by 63 places.

Answer (score 3):

The `1` here, is called an *integer constant*. By the norms specified in the standard, `C11`, chapter `§6.4.4.1` the syntax for the same is

> integer-constant:
>       *decimal-constant* integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>
>        *octal-constant* integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>
>        *hexadecimal-constant*
>   integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>

and regarding the Semantics,

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

and the table says, if there is no suffix, and the value is representable in the `int` range it should be considered as `int`. So, `1` here, is considered an `int`, which is of *generally* 4 bytes, or 32 bits, also same in your case.

To explicitly specify the `1` as `unsigned long` (64) bit, we can use the suffix, like

```
1UL << 63
```

should solve your issue.

<sup>**Please note: `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be of 64 bits. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits**. However, as long as you're using the platform where `unsigned long` is of 64 bits , you should be fine</sup>

Comment: `unsigned long long` is not guaranteed to be 64 bits either, it could be 128 bits or something like that.

Comment: @FUZxxl It is _at least_ 64 bits guranteed. I can shift 128 bit variable(s) to 64 bits places without any issues, in other case. :-)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `unsigned long long` may not be exactly 64 bits long (it's merely *at least* 64 bits long), your answer indicates the opposite.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks sir. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use `1ULL` since this will give you a 64-bit unsigned integer on 32 and 64 bit architecture.
On 32 Bit architecture `unsigned long` (and therefor `UL`) is only 32 bit long and will not solve the problem.

```
1ULL << 63
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `unsigned long long` is a type that is not available on C89 platforms.