# Problem with converting signed/unsigned int variables in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, bit-shift

I am making a circuit, that will pull data out of the 4011 shift register. So far it works fine, but as my number rolls over some value, strange things start to happen.

This code will cycle all of my 4011's.

```
  typedef unsigned long u_long;

  for (u_long i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(CLOCK_in,0);
    delayMicroseconds(0.2);

    bool bit = digitalRead(DATA_in);

    Serial.print(bit,BIN);

    if (bit) out |= (1 << i); 

    digitalWrite(CLOCK_in,1);
  }
  Serial.println((u_long)out);
  Serial.println((u_long)out,BIN);
```

From the first "print()" I get:

```
00000000000000010000000000000000
```

Which is what I am expecting as this is my input (And my goal is to convert it to unsigned long decimal - highest number is on 32bits). From the next `print()`, howeer, I get `4294934528`. And I think that is not correct. From the last `print()` function, where naive me expected the same answer as the first one, I get `11111111111111111000000000000000`

Where is the point that I am missing? Is there some problem with the bitshift part?

Comment: `the first "print()"` `the next "print()"` `the last "print()"` - I see only one `print` inside `Serial.print`. Please be more specific. Where is the "next" print? Where is the "last" print?

Comment: Please, post all the relevant code. If the error is related to the way variable `out` is printed, how can we help you if you don't even show how that variable is declared and initialized? All its lifecycle would be really welcome.

Comment: One bug that probably has nothing to do with the problem you're seeing: delayMicroseconds() takes an unsigned int. In the code above, the 0.2 is a floating-point number, which the compiler automatically converts to an unsigned int, resulting in 0. So the code above has the same effect as delayMicroseconds(0). If you need a delay under 1 microsecond, you can probably get away with no delayMicroseconds() call.

Comment: instead of typdef'ing your own type, just use the standard `uint32_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one issue that I spotted right away without an MCVE

```
for (u_long i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    ...
    if (bit) out |= (1 << i);
    ...
}
```

In Arduino `int` is a 16-bit type, and integer literals are of [`int` type by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714). Shifting by more than the bit width [invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11270492/995714), therefore your code has UB when i > 15

To fix that use the `L` suffix to make it a `long` literal

```
if (bit) out |= (1L << i);
```

But there's no reason to loop with a slow 32-bit variable in Arduino. Just use `int`, or even better `uint8_t`. Also use `uint32_t` with the standard `UINT32_C` macro for the output type so that you don't need to figure out the correct suffix

```
uint32_t out;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    ...
    if (bit) out |= UINT32_C(1) << i;
    ...
}
```

That said, you still need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)