# Confused using int type with bitwise operators and shifting in C

Tags: c, shift

Any thoughts on why I would get two different results, I suspect it has to do with a `signed` integer, but can't see the difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 32;
    printf("%x\n", (~0 << x));
    printf("%x\n", (~0 << 32));
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ffffffff
> 0

Comment: Looks like you've invoked undefined behavior:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784996/why-does-left-shift-operation-invoke-undefined-behaviour-when-the-left-side-oper

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: It's also UB for another reason, since it shifts an int by an amount greater than or equal to its width.  That's probably the immediate cause of this behavior: the runtime left-shift instruction masks the shift count, but the compile-time constant folding doesn't.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Don't you get some warning from your compiler? If not, turn up warning level. For GCC you can do this with `-Wall -Wextra`