Is left shifting a long long considered Undefined Behavior in C?
I know that the following code in C:
(1 << 31)

is considered Undefined Behavior due to the C standard (6.5.3 Shift Operators):

The result of the shift operation is undefined if the right operand is negative or if its value is greater than the number of bits in an int.

I’m just curious whether following C code:
(1LL << 63)

is also considered Undefined Behavior in any of the C standards.

You are reading documentation of DEC C langauge https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_001.HTM . Are you interested in "general" C, or specificaly in DEC C ? I believe DEC C has no long long.

General standard refers to the "the width of the left operand" instead of "an int". Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type

left shift of a 1 into the MSB (sign bit) is undefined behavior no matter what the size of the signed variable is

@KamilCuk DEC C standard was used as an example. I am interested in "general C"

@Dunes I don't think that this is a duplicate. The answer states, "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." However, my question still stands because 63 is not "greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand," which is 64.

@4386427 Thank you. I share your opinion, but I would like to see some evidence in the form of citations from the C standard.

@lollol Spec wise, it is the number of value bits that is of concern as larger than signed char can have padding.  Have not seen a padded signed type integer the wild.

C23 Section 6.5.7 says (my emphasis):

The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
the result is E1 × 2ᴱ², wrapped around. If E1 has a signed type and
nonnegative value, and E1 × 2ᴱ² is representable in the result type,
then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.

So if your platform's long long can represent 2⁶³, you're fine.  Since one bit must be used to indicate its sign, that means 1LL << 63 is UB if long long has 64 bits.
(long long cannot be smaller than 64 bits, but may be wider).

So, what is the answer? (1 << 31) is definitely undefined behavior, regardless of the platform on which it is compiled. According to C standards, long long holds a minimum of 64 bits, while int holds a minimum of 32 bits. The quotation sounds ambiguous. (1 << 31) "is representable in the result type" but the result is of undefined behavior on different platforms :)

No, 1 << 31 is defined behaviour if 2³¹ is representable (e.g. if the target's int type is 33 or more bits wide).  Similarly, 1LL << 63 is defined behaviour only if your long long is 65 or more bits.

@lollol: Re “(1 << 31) is definitely undefined behavior, regardless of the platform on which it is compiled”: That is false. 1 << 31 is defined if int has more than 32 bits.

Note that C89 defined the behavior of 1<<31 as yielding INT_MIN on platforms where int has 31 value bits, one sign bit, and zero padding bits, unsigned int has 32 value bits and no padding bits, and INT_MIN == -INT_MAX-1.

There are several things to consider (C17 6.5.7):

The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.


The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has
an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.


Width is formally defined for signed types in 6.2.6 as value bits plus sign bit. That means for a signed variable E1 of type intn_t, we may at most shift E1 << n. If we shift more than that we invoke undefined behavior, regardless if  E1 contains a negative value or not.
So it is not valid to "shift out" data from a signed type; this code probably has UB:
ms_byte_cleared = (my_signed32 << 40) >> 8;

In case E1 holds a negative value, left shifting always invokes undefined behavior.

In case shifting results in a larger value than what will fit in the promoted operand (essentially if we end up "shifting data into the sign bit"), then it is also undefined behavior.


The width of a long long is not defined by the C standard however. We just know that it is at least large enough to hold the value +9223372036854775807  (263-1) (defined in C17 5.2.4.2.1). Therefore we cannot strictly say that (1LL << 63) is definitely UB. We can however say that (int64_t)1 << 63 is UB since it results in the value 263 which is larger than the maximum value of an int64_t which is 263-1.

(1LL << 62) will give 4611686018427387904d or 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b. This is 63 bits.
(1LL << 63) will give -9223372036854775808d or -1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000n.
This is in two's complement representation, which is the smallest negative value representable by a 64-bit signed integer. This is 64 bits.
(1LL << 64) will give 0d or 0b, which would be considered Undefined Behavior.

You're describing likely behaviour, but the Standard specifically says this is undefined on a target using 64-bit twos-complement - see section 6.5.7 as linked from my answer.

I see. Nice book btw.
